# Why isn't the +2 reputation from accepting an answer on your own question negated when that question (as well as the answer) is deleted?

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, accepted-answer

Unless a post has a score > 3 and was visible on the site for > 60 days, the reputation gained and/or lost from it is reverted if it gets deleted.

Except it doesn't revert the +2 reputation for accepting an answer.

When a question gets deleted, its answers are also considered "implicitly deleted." So why does the question's OP keep the +2 reputation?

My account shows this inconsistency. I  <s>have</s>  (had) 103 reputation, and I gained the excess +2 reputation by accepting an answer to a question of mine (did that a long time ago) which is now deleted. Why wasn't the reputation negated?

Comment: [That is odd](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/131458/sag?tab=reputation). Since it didn't get cleaned up overnight I'd call that a bug.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/ Doesn't say that you lose 2 rep when an answer you accepted is removed. They should add that into the system.